# Xamarin back button Accessibility Name in iOS and Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, accessibility, navigationbar, back-button

In Xamarin Forms if you activate the navigation bar, that show you the title of the page and an arrow to use as a back button, when you have the screen reader activated and the back button is on focus, the talkback (for Android) says "unlabeled button".
I know how to set the Accessibility Name of general elements, but I don't know how to get the back button element, since it is not an istance.

Comment: In the android. You can get the back button, then add the `android:contentDescription` for the back button view like this thread.https://www.raywenderlich.com/240-android-accessibility-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I know how to set the accessibility name, but I don't know how to apply it to the back button, I don't know how to retrieve it

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Shell Navigation, create a CustomShellRenderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AppShell), typeof(CustomShellRenderer))]
namespace Droid.Renderers.CustomAppShell
{
    public class CustomShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {
        protected override IShellToolbarAppearanceTracker CustomToolbarAppearanceTracker()
        {
            return new CustomShellToolbarAppearanceTracker(this);
        }
    }
}
        
namespace Droid.CustomShell
{
    public class CustomShellToolbarAppearanceTracker : ShellToolbarAppearanceTracker
    {
        public override void SetAppearance(AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar toolbar, IShellToolbarTracker toolbarTracker, ShellAppearance appearance)
        {
            base.SetAppearance(toolbar, toolbarTracker, appearance);
            toolbar.NavigationContentDescription = "Custom Label Description”; // Set label here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61812787/set-automationproperties-to-back-button-of-the-navigation-bar-to-avoid-talkback for page level custom rendering. For better performance, customize at the navigation level instead of the page level.