# Set AutomationProperties to back button of the navigation bar to avoid TalkBack's "Unlabeled button"

Tags: xamarin.forms, accessibility, navigationbar, back-button

I'm developing an accessible cross platform application using Xamarin.Fomrs. I'm using `NavigationPage` to manage the navigation. When I am in a second page and I want to go back using the button in the navigation bar, TalkBack says: "unlabeled button".

How can I set `AutomationProperties` for this button? The main goal is to set different help texts depending on the current view. Is it possible

Comment: You need to subclass the `NavigationRenderer` in each platform, get the image from there & set its `AutiomationProperties`.

Comment: Thank you Mihail, I don't know what is the ```NativagionRenderer```, but I will check it

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

Comment: @Jon Hi, if using `NavigationPage` when navigating to next page , there will be a default back button . And click back button will back to previous page . You can share some code to explain your problem .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Hi, yes the back button automatically appears, there is no problem with this. The problem is when you activate TalkBack in the Android device, allows to blind people to use the app, but it is necessary to set AutomationProperties in each interesting view. When a view is focused TalkBack reads these properties, and "default back button"  is read like "unlabeled button", because there is no direct access to the button to set the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved my goal with this renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), typeof(AndroidNavigationPageRenderer))]
namespace SZukaldatzen.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class AndroidNavigationPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public AndroidNavigationPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            Activity context = (Activity)this.Context;
            var toolbar = context.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

            toolbar.NavigationContentDescription = "Go back";
        }
    }
}
```

Now TalkBack says "Go back" when back button is selected.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me. What worked for me (Xamarin 5, Android 11) was this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(NavigationPageCustomRenderer))]
namespace CustomRenderers
{
    public class NavigationPageCustomRenderer : NavigationPageRenderer
    {
        public NavigationPageCustomRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

        public override void AddChildrenForAccessibility(IList<Android.Views.View> views)
        {
            base.AddChildrenForAccessibility(views);

            var backButton = views.FirstOrDefault(x => x is Android.Widget.ImageButton && string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ContentDescription));
            if (backButton != null)
            {
                backButton.ContentDescription = "Go back";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For AndroidX I used the following:

```
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
           base.OnElementChanged(e);

           Activity context = (Activity)this.Context;
           var toolbar = context.FindViewById<AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

           if (toolbar != null)
           {
              toolbar.NavigationContentDescription = "Go back";
           }
        }
```